# Child Process not exiting in Piping

Tags: c, linux, pipe, execvp

I'm currently testing a program that executes the Linux command `echo Hello | wc` using piping.

The parent process in `main()` spawns two child processes, the first one which executes `echo Hello`, and the second one which executes `wc`. These two processes communicate via a pipe.

However, when I call `waitpid()` on the two child  processes, only the second process exits. The first process successfully runs `execvp()`, but hangs there.

Here is the supposed output of the code:

```
command 0
command 0 should exit
command 1
      1       1       6
```

If I uncommment the line `waitpid(id[0],&status,0);`
then the output is

```
command 0
command 0 should exit
command 1
```

```
int test(pid_t id[])
{
    int i;
    int pipefd[2];

    char *cat_args[] = {"echo","Hello", NULL};
    char *grep_args[] = {"wc", NULL};

    // make a pipe
    pipe(pipefd);

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        id[i] = fork();

        if (id[i] == -1){
            printf("Unable to create child process");
            fprintf(stderr,"fork() failed to spawn child process");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if (id[i] == 0){
            printf("command ");
            printf("%d\n",i);
            
            if (i == 0){
                dup2(pipefd[0],STDIN_FILENO);
            }
            else if (i == 1){
                dup2(pipefd[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
            }

            // Close pipes
            close(pipefd[0]);
            close(pipefd[1]);

            if (i == 1){
                execvp(*cat_args,cat_args); //exit(0) normally
            }
            else if (i == 0){
                printf("command 0 should exit\n");
                execvp(*grep_args,grep_args); 
                printf("command 0 exited\n"); //If first child exits, should print it out
            }
            
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the main function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ 
    pid_t id[2];
    test(id);

    int status;
    
    // If this is uncommented, the piped Linux command is never ran
    // and main() never exits
    //waitpid(id[0],&status,0); 

    waitpid(id[1],&status,0); // This works
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your comment is incorrect.  If you uncomment that line, the `wc` command does execute, but it never finishes and so never prints any data (its output buffer never gets flushed).  If you leave the line commented, `wc` command is only terminating because the parent exits and all of its file descriptors get closed.

Answer (score 1):

The sub-process running `wc` hangs because the pipe is still readable despite the sub-process running `echo Hello` died. `wc` still waits for something to read through the pipe.

Why is the pipe still readable? Because you didn't close it in the parent process, the one that does the two `fork`s. Therefore, the parent can still read and write to the pipe and the `wc` sub-process stays blocked on `read()` and never receives an EOF.

BTW, your `printf("command 0 exited\n")` is useless since nothing is executed after a successful `execvp()`.