# Strange behavior with Child process

Tags: c, linux, shell, pipe, execvp

I have a question about the behavior of child processes. The intention of this test program is to run the Linux command `echo Hello | wc` using piping.

My commands were not working, and it turns out the wrong c-string is being called.

The expected output is:

```
command 0
echo
command 1
wc
```

However, I get:

```
command 0
echo 
command 1
Hello
```

I only get the expected output when I comment out
execvp(), when the child processes are not being exited.

Here is the test function:

```
int test(pid_t id[])
{
    int i;
    int pipefd[2];

    char *cat_args[] = {"echo","Hello", NULL};
    char *grep_args[] = {"wc", NULL};
    char **arr[] = {cat_args,grep_args};

    // make a pipe 
    pipe(pipefd);

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        id[i] = fork();

        if (id[i] == -1){
            printf("Unable to create child process");
            fprintf(stderr,"fork() failed to spawn child process");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if (id[i] == 0){
            printf("command ");
            printf("%d\n",i);
            
            if (i == 0){
                dup2(pipefd[0],STDIN_FILENO);
            }
            else if (i == 1){
                dup2(pipefd[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
            }
            // Close pipes for child processes
            close(pipefd[0]);
            close(pipefd[1]);

            printf("%s\n",*arr[i]);
            //To simply and simulate problem, can replace execvp() with exit(0);
            execvp(*arr[i],arr[i]);
        }
    }
    // Close pipes of parent process    close(pipefd[0]);
    close(pipefd[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the main function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ 
    pid_t id[2];
    test(id);

    int status;
    
    waitpid(id[0],&status,0); 
    waitpid(id[1],&status,0); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you keep asking the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66991268/child-process-not-exiting-in-piping

Answer (score 1):

`printf` writes to stdout, so it's affected by your `dup2(pipefd[1],STDOUT_FILENO);`, and therefore goes into the pipe instead of on your screen.

You should instead write your diagnostics messages to stderr:

```
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", *arr[i]);
```

The reason why you see `Hello` is that this is the output of your reversed pipeline.

```
wc | echo Hello
```

If you want to show the `wc` output `1 1 6`, you should flip them.